# Prove that $a^2+ab+b^2\ge 0$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality

How to prove that $a^2+ab+b^2\ge 0$?

Obviously the squares are positive, but how can I be sure that $ab$ doesn't become too negative with a certain combination of $a$ and $b$?

Comment: if $|A| \le |B|$, $|AB| \le |B^2|$; otherwise $|AB| < |A^2|$

Comment: An older post about the same inequality: [Inequality: $x^2+y^2+xy\ge 0$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/920605/inequality-x2y2xy-ge-0)

Comment: $ab$ cannot become *too negative* because $a^2+2ab+b^2=(a+b)^2\ge 0$ $\Rightarrow$ $ab\ge -\frac12(a^2+b^2)$.

Comment: This question is also a variation of the question of your post: [How can I prove that $xy\leq x^2+y^2$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/357272/how-can-i-prove-that-xy-leq-x2y2)

Comment: Same as http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1074100/if-x-and-y-are-not-both-0-then-x2-xy-y2-0/1074104#1074104

Answer (score 20, accepted):

$a^2+ab+b^2= (a+ \frac{1}{2}b)^2 + \frac{3}{4}b^2$

One may prefer symmetry:
$2(a^2+ab+b^2)= a^2 +b^2+(a+b)^2$.

Answer (score 2):

There is yet another of seeing this.

Since $ab$ is between $-2ab$ and $2ab$, the quantity $a^2+ab+b^2$ must be between $a^2-2ab+b^2$ and $a^2+2ab+b^2$. But these two quantities obey

$$a^2-2ab+b^2=(a-b)^2\ge0 \tag{1}$$
and 
$$a^2+2ab+b^2=(a+b)^2\ge0 \tag{2}$$
with equality only if $a=b$ for (1), $a=-b$ for (2),or $a=b=0$ for (1) and (2).

Since $a^2+ab+b^2$ is inclusively between two non-negative quantities, it must be non-negative.

This motivates why the discriminant is so important - in cases such as $a^2+3ab+b^2=(a+b)^2+ab$, the quantity is not between those in (1) and (2), and completing the square will lead to a difference of squares rather than an addition of squares, i.e $(a+\frac{3}{2}b)^2-(\frac{\sqrt5}{2}b)^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Any second-degree polynomial with a negative discriminant always has the same sign. 
That follows from completing the square, as Khue did. In our case:

$$ 4(a^2+ab+b^2) = (2a+b)^2+\color{red}{3}b^2 $$
and that $\color{red}{3}$ is the opposite of the discriminant of $a^2+ab+b^2$, i.e. $1^2-4\cdot 1\cdot 1=-3.$

Answer (score 1):

Or, one can argue *via* the sign of $ab$:

if

$ab \ge 0, \tag{1}$

then, since

$a^2, b^2 \ge 0$ for all $a, b \in \Bbb R$,

$a^2 + b^2 + ab \ge 0; \tag{2}$

if

$ab < 0, \tag{3}$

then evidently

$ab = -\vert a \vert \vert b \vert, \tag{4}$

and we can without loss of generality assume that

$\vert a \vert \ge \vert b \vert, \tag{5}$

since the expression $a^2 + ab + b^2$ is invariant under the interchange $a \leftrightarrow b$.  Thus,

$a^2 + ab = \vert a \vert^2 - \vert a \vert \vert b \vert$
$= \vert a \vert (\vert a \vert - \vert b \vert) \ge 0, \tag{6}$

whence

$a^2 + ab + b^2 \ge 0, \tag{7}$

since $b^2 \ge 0$ for all $b \in \Bbb R$.