# How to prove the below inequality is always satisfied?

Tags: inequality, algorithms, quadratics

Given inequality -: x<sup>2</sup> + 2xy + 2y<sup>2</sup> > 0 always satisfies the inequality for every x and y, where x and y are real numbers(x and y are not equal to 0).

How to prove this without using any graph? Is there any mathematical formula or something like that?

Second example -: x<sup>2</sup> + 10xy + 2y<sup>2</sup> > 0 does not satisfy the inequality always.

Comment: Yes, "something like that". You can really prove it mathematically. See also the example of [$x^2+xy+y^2\ge 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/920605/inequality-x2y2xy-ge-0).

Comment: To prove the second example doesn’t satisfy the inequality always, you just need a counterexample, such as $x=1, y=-1$

Answer (score 1):

It is $$x^2+2xy+y^2+y^2=(x+y)^2+y^2>0$$